# JQuery Mobile Image Layout

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

[image: Image Layout]

I am creating a mobile website using JQuery Mobile Framework and I'm trying to get my home page to look like this. I have the menu and user part finished.

However I cannot get my images to stack like this. I want them to be like buttons/links to different pages but when I do it:

1. It doesn't fit the screen correctly, it leaves white bars on the left.
2. it doesn't resize correctly and just crops half the image out.

I've tried styling the images in my css with:

```
<style>
.ui-grid-b img {
    width  : auto;
    height : auto;
}
</style>
```

Can someone please give tell me how I can do this with images using JQuery Mobile?

(The design above was created by me as a digital mockup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My rank on this site is too low to add a comment, so I must add this as an answer.

what does your html look like? How is anyone supposed to answer this question with a small snippet of css?

What are you wanting to happen at none mobile screen resolutions, are they going to continue to stay stacked like that? Jquery Mobile emphasizes progressive enhancement, but its still a consideration....

Auto auto isn't going to give you want you want, you;re going to want the width to be 100% of your container and your height can be auto. Maybe with a max height set to prevent it from going crazy..

Here is a good example of rows to columns with stacked content (not images) on a code [pen](http://codepen.io/Cheesetoast/pen/KFAaq).

```
code snippet
```